# Shoutcast broadcasting in android

Tags: android, shoutcast, broadcasting

I've checked the many blogs and forums and github but nothing found related/help for implementing shoutcast v1 or v2 in android, only ref which is helpful I've found in github is this:

https://github.com/fatihsokmen/android-icecast-broadcast

but above code only work with icecast server and also very limited use and files which is used for broadcasting is *.so files so we can not change or override the exiting methods.

is there any guide or helpful link or source code which I can use to build shoutcast broadcasting in android, please share with me.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: I also tryed lots but did not found such helpful code